# Is it possible to verify input in the string format?

Tags: c++, string, validation, while-loop, user-input

The code below is the module that is supposed to check if another game should be played. However, even when typing yes or no, it still detects newGame as false, thus causing the while loop to iterate indefinitely regardless of input. What is the issue?

```
string askNewGame()
{
    //Declare variable to store whether to run another game.
    string newGame = "no";

    //Ask if the program should run another game.
    cout << "Do you want to play another game? (yes/no)\n";
    cin >> newGame;

    //Ensure yes or no are entered.
    while (newGame != "yes" || "no")
    {
        cout << "Please enter yes or no.\n";
        cin >> newGame;
    }
    return newGame;
}
```

Comment: `(newGame != "yes" || "no")` doesn't mean what you think. You probably want: `(newGame != "yes" && newGame != "no")`.

Comment: Yeah - what @wohlstad said: The expression you're testing is parsed as `(newGame != "yes") || "no"`. So, as a string-constant decays to a **non-null** pointer, `"no"` will always be true.

Comment: `while ((newGame != "yes") || ("no" != nullptr))` which probably isn't what you want.